# Nginx redirect rule to sub-directory

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have an old PHP application running with Apache, for now I need to switch to use Nginx

htaccess redirecting rule

```
php_value upload_max_filesize "5M"

AddType text/x-component .htc


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /brand/kit/summer-icecream/lacne

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/admin/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/setup/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/support/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/share/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/rss/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/output/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/upload/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/app_api/)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ share/admin/$1.php [L]

RewriteRule app_api/(.+)\.php$ share/app_api/$1.php [L]
```

I have tried several way to redirect such as below but it seems doesn't work at all, it doesn't pass the PHP file to PHP-FPM

```
location ~ brand/kit/summer-icecream/lacne/(.+)\.php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
           rewrite ^/brand/kit/summer-icecream/lacne/(.+)\.php$ /brand/kit/summer-icecream/lacne/share/admin/$1.php redirect;
        }
    }

    location ~ (.+)\.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
       fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
       fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
       fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST $host;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_config;
    }
```

For testing, the request URI is:
http://127.0.0.1:8989/brand/kit/summer-icecream/lacne/login.php

Comment: Well you can run nginx and apache parallel because its a common setup - let the old thing run on apache and use nginx to proxy_pass it, isnt that an option?

Comment: well that way will make the stack more complex for further maintenance, if there is no option with Nginx, I have to come back with Apache

Comment: Perhaps nginx isn't listening on 127.0.0.1:8989.  Hard to say with only an extract from your configuration.

Comment: Using `if (!-e $request_filename) { ... }` is a bad practice (usually this construction suggested by online apache-to-nginx configuration converters). You can try [this](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx) converter (made by [Danila Vershinin](https://serverfault.com/users/242885/danila-vershinin)).